# Open new window when click on ASP.NET Chart Image in MVC 3 application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, mschart

I have an ASP.NET Chart with drilldown in MVC 3 Application.

The drilldown url is constructed in the Controller and  is assigned to the Chart Datapoint. Now, when i click on this datapoint on the chart, a different view is rendered where the drilldown data is shown. This view opens in the same window.

I want the drilldown data to be shown in a new window.  I have used Point.MapareaAttributes ([as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554933/open-a-new-window-using-mapareaattributes-in-microsoft-chart-control)) but it seems to not work.

The URL has to be constructed in the Business logic layer only.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with the following code my team mate provided

point.Url = "javascript:void window.showModalDialog('" +
url.Action("ABC", "BCD", new { segment = point.AxisLabel, severity = sev })
+ "','Defect Drill down','dialogHeight:380px;dialogWidth:720px;unadorned:yes;scroll:auto');";